# Second Derivative Test Saddle Points Calc 3

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am using the second derivative test, which uses $D = f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b)-[f_{xy}(a,b)]^2$. I am told that if $D<0$, then $f(a,b)$ must be a saddle point. The intuition behind this is that $f_{xx}(a,b)$ and $f_{yy}(a,b)$ must be opposite signs to yield a negative $D$ value.

However, what happens if $0<f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b) < [f_{xy}(a,b)]^2$ Wouldn't that make the point not a saddle point? Because both $f_{xx}(a,b)$ and $f_{yy}(a,b)$ could be the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

The number $f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b)-\bigl(f_{xy}(a,b)\bigr)^2$ is the product of the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}f_{xx}(a,b)&f_{xy}(a,b)\\f_{yx}(a,b)&f_{yy}(a,b)\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ of $f$ at $(a,b)$. So, if it is smaller than $0$, that product is negative and so one of the eigenvalues is positive and the other one is negative. So, yes, it *is* a saddle point.

Comment: I think you interpreted my question differently. What I meant to ask was if $D<0$, couldn't $f(a,b)$ not be a saddle point?

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood you. What do you think now?

Comment: I think $D$ can be negative and the point can be a relative min/max. Because if $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are both positive, but they are less than $[f_{xy}]^2$, then $D<0$. What does this case mean?

Comment: Nothing. Suppose that $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-4xy$. In this case, $f_{xx}(0)=f_{yy}(0)=2$. But we still have a saddle point, because, for instance, $f(x,0)\geqslant0$, but $f(x,x)\leqslant0$.